# Replace null value in Table before TransformColumns

Tags: error-handling, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

In a PowerBI datasource I have a table with a Column "SPRINT" in one Column. This column contains a LIST of values or null (value comes from JIRA API).

[image]

In the next step I extract the values using `Table.TransformColumns` to geht the string out:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"PREVIOUS", {"Sprint", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text})
```

Result:

[image]

in the next steps I do a `SplitColumn` in order to get the information out of this SPRINT string that I want to have.

In the end, all rows where SPRINT was null end in several columns with ERROR.

So my question is, how can I manage to prevent getting all those errors? Ideally I would expect to transform the SPRINT Column values where SPRINT is null into something that does not end with ERROR and avoid the execution of SPLIT function in case it does not make any sense.

I managed to add `Table.ReplaceErrorValues` in the end for all affected columns - and this works but it seems to be quite an overhead to me and I try to keep the transformations as slim as possible because the JIRA API is slow and tending to timeout with a specific number of rows and operations.

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

If it is null, you can simply add one more step after expanding and replace error with null or any other value you are expecting against null.